# MS Teams Send Activity Notifications Error "Topic value is outside of permissible boundaries",

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am getting below given error when Sending Activity Notifications for the MSTeams using GraphAPI Error: "Topic value is outside of permissible boundaries".

Tried to find out the limit for Topic but was unable to do so.

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Could you please share more information on what/how you are trying to do? Also please go through these links - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#example-3-notify-a-user-about-an-event-using-a-custom-topic, https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/csharp

Comment: I am trying to send Teams Activity Notificaiton using GrapAPI. I am setting the JSON Payload for the same. I am using SubEntityID to pass some values with "|" seperator. WIth the Long value to send it gives me above error. So I assume there should be some character limit for the JSON body of Topic.

Comment: As mentioned in the [teamworkActivityTopic resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamworkactivitytopic?view=graph-rest-1.0) document, the source of type entityUrl must be a Microsoft Graph URL. Could you please confirm if your url is proper?